# Specify different conda.exe in Windows

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I have two conda.exe in different folder. How can I specify the default program that the command `conda` will refer to in the prompt?

Comment: it impossible to have 2 anaconda installed in the same system unless the 2nd one is installed on vm. So explain more what do you mean? by having 2 conda installed, maybe you mean 2 virtual environments?

Comment: One is miniconda and the other one is anaconda.